# Raspbian, Can I resize just one desktop icon?

Tags: desktop

So if I wanted to make my desktop icons bigger, I just go to file manager preferences and select the size of icons I want.  But what if I wanted just one icon smaller than the rest?  Is there a workaround that would allow me to do this?  I'm assuming if I resize the image for the icon it will just scale it to suit.
So maybe in my [desktop entry] I can add something that uses small, medium or large icon that is setup in file manager preferences?  this would help, but what is the command or can this be added to a Desktop entry?

Comment: I have done the 'resize icon' thing and whilst it does look good and what I need, I cannot get rid of the text under the icon.  any clues on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just place a small (e.g. 32x32) picture in the middle of a bigger (e.g. 256x256) transparent image, and use that as an icon.

Comment: I love the solution man...that is cool.  I just might do that.